# having errors in Xcode while compiling saying that used twice

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

:0: error: filename "SurveyViewController.swift" used twice: '/Users/raeessamman/Downloads/fwdsurver/SurveyViewController.swift' and '/Users/raeessamman/Desktop/IOS Development projects/SammanMRA-cobsccomp191p-036/NIBM COVID19/NIBM COVID19/Controller/SurveyViewController.swift'
:0: note: filenames are used to distinguish private declarations with the same name
Command CompileSwiftSources failed with a nonzero exit code

Comment: Try to clean the build folder and build again

Answer (score 0):

search with this name "SurveyViewController" in your project
you will find that you declare it twice. you must change or delete one of them.

if you didn't find it you must search in "project.pbxproj" file and you will find two paths with the same name.

to open the "project.pbxproj" file you should go to "YourApp.xcodeproj" then you double click in it, menu will open select "show package contents" then you will find 2 files one of them is "project.pbxproj".